# Asking for overlapping date ranges in same SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in an oracle SQL database.

Its columns are VEHICLE_ID, GEAR_ID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, AA.

The startdate and enddate are representing the date range within the gear is active for the specific vehicle.

My problem is that I need find the same gears of the same vehicle that have overlapping dates.

I came up with this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT G.* FROM VEHICLE_GEARS G JOIN (SELECT A.*, B.CNT FROM VEHICLE_GEARS A JOIN
(SELECT VEHICLE_ID, GEAR_ID, COUNT(GEAR_ID) CNT FROM VEHICLE_GEARS GROUP BY 

VEHICLE_ID, GEAR_ID HAVING COUNT(GEAR_ID) > 1) B
    ON A.VEHICLE_ID = B.VEHICLE_ID AND A.GEAR_ID = B.GEAR_ID) ASDF ON
    G.VEHICLE_ID = ASDF.VEHICLE_ID AND G.GEAR_ID = ASDF.GEAR_ID
WHERE 
    NOT(
        TRUNC(ASDF.STARTDATE) >= TRUNC(G.ENDDATE)
        OR
        TRUNC(ASDF.ENDDATE) <= TRUNC(G.STARTDATE)
        )
    ORDER BY 1, 5
```

The problem is that this considers overlapping even the dates that have equal enddate of gear with the startdate of the gear, which I do not want but even after removing the equality from the where clauses the results are the same.

Please help, thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Sample data (after the above query):

```
000000006   2012-02-20 00:00:00 3   2999-12-31 00:00:00 804
000000006   1991-07-01 00:00:00 9   2999-12-31 00:00:00 804
000000147   1991-07-01 00:00:00 1   1992-10-08 00:00:00 601
000000147   1992-10-08 00:00:00 2   2999-12-31 00:00:00 601
```

What was expected is that vehicle 000000147 should not be in the result set because the enddate of gear 601 is the same as the stardate of its second "instance".
The first two records (vehicle 00000006) is correct because the dates of gear 804 are overlapping.

SAMPLE TABLE DATA:

```
000000000   2014-02-25 00:00:00 1   2999-12-31 00:00:00 302
000000000   2006-12-15 00:00:00 3   2999-12-31 00:00:00 604
000000000   2006-12-15 00:00:00 4   2999-12-31 00:00:00 605
000000006   1991-07-01 00:00:00 1   2999-12-31 00:00:00 601
000000006   2016-01-18 00:00:00 10  2999-12-31 00:00:00 605
000000006   2012-02-20 00:00:00 3   2999-12-31 00:00:00 804
000000006   1991-07-01 00:00:00 9   2999-12-31 00:00:00 804
000000147   1991-07-01 00:00:00 1   1992-10-08 00:00:00 601
000000147   1992-10-08 00:00:00 2   2999-12-31 00:00:00 601
```

EXPECTED RESULTS:

```
000000000   2006-12-15 00:00:00 4   2999-12-31 00:00:00 605
000000006   2016-01-18 00:00:00 10  2999-12-31 00:00:00 605
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What else is needed? Isn't my question clear?

Comment: Some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LAG` and `LEAD` analytic functions and then you do not need to use any self-joins:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICLE_GEARS ( vehicle_id, startdate, enddate, gear_id ) AS
SELECT '000000000', DATE '2014-02-25', DATE '2999-12-31', 302 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- No duplicate vehicle & gear
SELECT '000000000', DATE '2006-12-15', DATE '2999-12-31', 604 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- No duplicate vehicle & gear
SELECT '000000000', DATE '2006-12-15', DATE '2999-12-31', 605 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- No duplicate vehicle & gear
SELECT '000000006', DATE '1991-07-01', DATE '2999-12-31', 601 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- No duplicate vehicle & gear
SELECT '000000006', DATE '2016-01-18', DATE '2999-12-31', 605 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- No duplicate vehicle & gear
SELECT '000000006', DATE '2012-02-20', DATE '2999-12-31', 804 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Overlaps previous
SELECT '000000006', DATE '1991-07-01', DATE '2999-12-31', 804 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Overlaps next
SELECT '000000147', DATE '1991-07-01', DATE '1992-10-08', 601 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Same end date as next start date
SELECT '000000147', DATE '1992-10-08', DATE '2999-12-31', 601 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Same start date as previous end date
SELECT '000000567', DATE '2018-01-01', DATE '2018-12-31', 203 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Overlaps next
SELECT '000000567', DATE '2018-12-01', DATE '2019-01-10', 203 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Overlaps previous and next
SELECT '000000567', DATE '2018-12-31', DATE '2019-01-10', 203 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Overlaps previous and next
SELECT '000000567', DATE '2018-12-31', DATE '2019-01-31', 203 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Overlaps previous
SELECT '000000567', DATE '2019-01-31', DATE '2019-02-28', 203 FROM DUAL           -- Same start date as previous
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT vehicle_id,
       startdate,
       enddate,
       gear_id
FROM   (
  SELECT G.*,
         LAG( enddate   ) OVER ( PARTITION BY vehicle_id, gear_id ORDER BY startdate, enddate ) AS prev_enddate,
         LEAD( startdate ) OVER ( PARTITION BY vehicle_id, gear_id ORDER BY startdate, enddate ) AS next_startdate
  FROM   VEHICLE_GEARS G
)
WHERE  prev_enddate > startdate
AND    ( enddate <= next_startdate OR next_startdate IS NULL );
```

**Output**:

```
VEHICLE_ID | STARTDATE | ENDDATE   | GEAR_ID
:--------- | :-------- | :-------- | ------:
000000006  | 20-FEB-12 | 31-DEC-99 |     804
000000567  | 31-DEC-18 | 31-JAN-19 |     203
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=262e374e359ff9b29db74c4121aedbea)*

Answer (score 0):

In its smiplest form, this gives everything in the table that starts before another line ends where the gear and vehicle are the same using a simple self join:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from VEHICLE_GEARS t1
inner join VEHICLE_GEARS t2
  on t1.gear_id = t2.gear_id
  and t1.vehicle_id = t2.vehicle_id
  and t2.startdate < t1.enddate
  and t1.startdate < t2.startdate
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the query that you provided does not however bring the expected results. I am getting result with vehicles that does not have overlapping dates with the same gear id. This is an example: 000000000 2014-02-25 00:00:00 1 2999-12-31 00:00:00 302, 000000000 2006-12-15 00:00:00 3 2999-12-31 00:00:00 604. The dates are overlapping but the gears are 302 and 604. If the gears were the same then it would be correct.