# How to insert rows in Oracle SQL by checking other rows in the same table

Tags: database

I am trying to design a hospital database and I have a table called Admission as such

| admitID | admitDate | disDate | bed_ID | pat_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ADM0001 | 2021-02-17 | 2021-02-20 | B0003 | P0002 |

The sample record above means that Patient P0002 has been admitted on 17th of February and is staying on Bed B0003

How do I prevent a situation whereby someone inserts a record with a bed that is still being occupied?

E.g. inserting 2021-02-18 as an admitDate and also inserting B0003 as the bedID as the next record.

Comment: You do that in your programming logic before inserting in the DB

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686590/asking-for-overlapping-date-ranges-in-same-sql-table